# Java app on tomcat server saving files on server instead of path

Tags: java, file, tomcat, io

I currently have a application a Java web application on Tomcat 7 server that is supposed to generate files and save them on a path specified by the user.  This works fine when i test it on my local machine but when i deploy to a dev server, the files get saved on the following path "conf/Catalina/localhost" on the server with the specified path as part of the name.

For instance, if i set the directory to where I want the file saved to "C:\Users\kbbj\Desktop", the files gets saved on the server as "C:\Users\kbbj\Desktop\filename.ext".

This is my code that creates a Word file (notice the last part where it saves):

```
public static void createWordDoc(Request request) throws Docx4JException {
        String filename = request.study+"_data_specs_v"+request.currentVersion+".docx";

        wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

        //Create titles
        String title = request.study+" Data Specifications v."+request.currentVersion;
        String subtitle = request.analysis.analysisType+" Analysis for "+request.purpose.purpose;

        // Add titles to document
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText("Title",title);
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText("Subtitle",subtitle);
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("");
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("");

        //Create specification table
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText("Heading2", "Specifications");
        factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();

        Tbl table = factory.createTbl();
        Tr tableRow = factory.createTr();

        addStyledTableCell(tableRow, "Variable Name",true,null);
        addStyledTableCell(tableRow, "Values",true,null);
        addStyledTableCell(tableRow, "Method",true,null);
        addStyledTableCell(tableRow, "Analyst Instructions",true,null);
        table.getContent().add(tableRow);

        System.out.println("Number of specs: "+request.specs.size());
        //Add specs to table
        for(Specification spec:request.specs){
            Tr newRow = factory.createTr();
            addTableCell(newRow, spec.variable.name!=null ? spec.variable.name : "");
            addTableCell(newRow, spec.variable.codeList!=null ? spec.variable.getCodeListAsString():"");
            addTableCell(newRow, spec.method!=null ? spec.method.method:"");
            addTableCell(newRow, spec.instructions!=null ? spec.instructions:"");
            table.getContent().add(newRow);
        }


        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(table);

        //Save the file on project directory
        String filepath = request.directory+"\\"+filename;
        System.out.println("file path: "+filepath);
        wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File(filepath));
    }
```

Any ideas of what is going on?
Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible for 2 reasons:

1. security, the user your are using to start tomcat service not have access outside Catalina/localhost so you can not create files out side folder have privileges on, and it is not recommended to run tomcat service with root "if it is possible"
2. OS is different, if you are hosting your application on linux so you do not have c: drive at all

suggest you can make relative paths and use `File.mkdirs()` to create nested folders